# R - Adding series to multiple plots

Tags: r, plot

I have the following plot:

```
plot.ts(returns)
```

[image]

I have another dataframe `ma_sd` which contains the rolling SD from moving averages of the above returns. The df is structured exactly like `returns`. Is there a simple way to add each line to the corresponding plots?

`lines(1:N, ma_sd)` seemed intuitive, but it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: Is `ma_sd` a time serie, i.e. a `ts` class?

Comment: No it's a dataframe.

Comment: Can you use par(mfrow=c(3,1)) and then just draw three plots separately?

Comment: That's an option, but I thought there may be a more scalable way of doing it, considering the plots all have the same structure.

Comment: Can you make `ma_sd` into a ts object with the same structure as `returns`?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see you doing this is to plot them separately. This code is a bit clunky but will allow you full flexibility to be able to specify labels and axis ranges. You can build on this.

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1),oma=c(5,4,4,2),mar=c(0,0,0,0))
time<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(1:length(returns[,1])),length(returns[,1]),3))
plot(time[,1],returns[,1],type='l',xaxt='n')
points(time[,1],ma_sd[,1],type='l',col='red')
plot(time[,2],returns[,2],type='l',xaxt='n')
points(time[,2],ma_sd[,2],type='l',col='red')
plot(time[,3],returns[,3],type='l')
points(time[,3],ma_sd[,3],type='l',col='red')
```